# ElasticSearch Setting

Tags: elasticsearch, config

I know that we can post the setting to elasticsearch with this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

However is there anyway to store those value in the config file similiar to store the mapping in the .json in config/mapping folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll be making changes to the elasticsearch.yml file. Here's a sample:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/config/elasticsearch.yml

And here is some documentation on the configuration options:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html